# yii filevalidator doesnt show error on tooLarge file but a php warning at the top

Tags: php, file-upload, yii, max-size

i only want to allow files with max 1MB

```
 array('taskfile', 'file', 'allowEmpty' => true, 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 1,'on' => 'newTask, edit'),
```

now, my php.ini allows a post_max_filesize of 8MB.
if the file is under 8MB but larger than 1MB the file validation error appears correctly.

but if the file is > 8MB no error from yii appears but from php itself. problem is, it appears also in the live mode.

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 12028878 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

why doesnt yii check the filesize and throw the validation error? and how can i achieve this?

#### SOLVED:

ok i solved it with a little helper method.

i added a new validation rule

```
 array('taskfile', 'checkMaxPostSize', 'on' => 'newTask, edit'),
```

and the helper method

```
    public function checkMaxPostSize($attribute) {
    if (isset($this->taskfile)) {
        if ($this->taskfile->size > 1024*1024*1 ) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'file is tooooooo large');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check if you have not another var to check POST_MAX_SIZE (as suhosin) ?

Comment: thx, i made a lil workaround... i editted my question with the solution.

Comment: if you wish you can answer your own question, and accept that answer, its ok to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think your original problem was the `'on'` portion of your validator. When you have multiple validators, they need to be an array; the correct code would look like this:

```
array('taskfile', 'file', 'allowEmpty' => true, 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 1,'on' => array('newTask', 'edit')),
```